# XPath parsing nodes with namespace

Tags: xml, xpath

Lets say I have this XML:

```
<xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
    <xfa:data>
        <TopmostSubform>
              <!-- more nodes -->
        </TopmostSubform>
    </xfa:data>
</xfa:datasets>
```

I want to search for nodes based on the route of the document.

Shouldnt `"/*/*/*[local-name()='TopmostSubform']"` work?

```
Node dom = getRootDom();
String xpathExpression = "/*/*/*[local-name()='TopmostSubform']";
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expression = xPath.compile(xpathExpression);
Node node = (Node) expression.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

This gives me `Node == null`.

Comment: You need to register the namespace `xfa`. Would need to know the programming language you are using

Comment: its in Java, just using the default libraries.

Comment: Yes that should work (i.e. should select the `<TopmostSubform>` element). For further help in debugging the problem, you'll probably need to show your Java code and tell what result you got vs. what result you expected. And @hek2mgl, he won't need to register the namespace unless he uses it. You don't need one for `*` or for `local-name()`.